# Server-side routing with Meteor.js + React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs

My question is how to correctly set up routes on the server side that are connected with react.js on the client.

I'm working on an application built on [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app), which I'm integrating with [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). The application is going to require a number of routes. My main issue (so far), is that I anticipate a lot of server side api calls using their respective (secure) secret keys. The calls will be something like

```
Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=perkytweets");
```

Obviously, these should be server side for security reasons. I will then handle the data on the server and pass what I need over to react, to then be rendered on the DOM.

It seems that [Flow Router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) is not ideal, although it seems to be the go-to for `Meteor+React` applications, since it focuses on client side routing rather than the server side routing that I require.

Typically, Meteor.js applications are built with [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router), but I've had some difficulty getting `React` to work alongside of `Iron Router`.

**Please Note:** the following code doesn't seem to indicate a need for anything server side, which is because I'm just getting everything set up with a tutorial, but it eventually will...right now just trying to get routes working.

I have been doing the following:

---

**REACT CODE BELOW:**

**client/main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

**client/main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

**imports/ui/App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Spot from './Spot.jsx';

// App component - represents the whole app
export default class App extends Component {
  getSpots() {
    return [
      { _id: 1, text: 'This is task 1' },
      { _id: 2, text: 'This is task 2' },
      { _id: 3, text: 'This is task 3' },
    ];
  }

  renderSpots() {
    return this.getSpots().map((spot) => (
      <Spot key={spot._id} spot={spot} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>List</h1>
        </header>
        <ul>
          {this.renderSpots()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**imports/ui/Spot.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

// Task component - represents a single todo item
export default class Spot extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.spot.text}</li>
    );
  }
}

Spot.propTypes = {
  // This component gets the task to display through a React prop.
  // We can use propTypes to indicate it is required
  spot: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

---

**Attempted Fix #1:**

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('homePage');
});
```

**client/main.html**

```
<tempate name="homePage">
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="render-target"></div>
    </body>
</template>
```

Here is the result (the Iron Router message means that the routes have not been implemented alongside of react)[image]

Comment: What do you mean by server-side API calls? (Meteor methods? Subscriptions? REST calls?) I have a hard time undestanding your problem, maybe since your post doesn't contain a question. :)

Comment: fair point: My question is how to correctly set up routes on the server side that are connected with react.js on the client. Calls would be something like: Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=perkytweets");

Comment: I still don't really understand. What do you mean by server-side routes? Do you want to achieve server-side React rendering? If yes, then [Flow Router SSR](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/tree/ssr) might help you.

Comment: Going along with this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975199/when-to-use-client-side-routing-or-server-side-routing) and this page (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/environments.html), I'm wondering how I can build a react/meteor app that does a lot of server side api calls but then only sends specific data (data that is safe to be exposed) to be used/rendered client side.

Comment: There's no need for server-side routing to achieve this. Just create a Meteor method that performs the API call on the server, processes the reply, and then sends only as much data to the client that's required to render the page.

Comment: How can you get react.js to handle the data sent from the Meteor method?

Comment: The answer is too long for a comment, check out my post.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use server-side routing here, just create a server-side Meteor method to perform the API calls, and display their results.

This example component calls a method upon mounting, and handles its return value asynchronously.

```
export class Pony extends React.Component {

  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    Meteor.call("call-pony-name-api", customPonyParameter, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {...}
      this.setState({ponyName: result.ponyName});
    });
  } 
}
```