# Redirecting to another page using a button click

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect

I want to redirect to another web page when I click a button. Please find the following code

js

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {

$scope.redirect = function()
{
console.log($location.url());

};

}
```

I can obtain the current url using $location.url() which is follows

```
http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page
```

What I want to do is i want to redirect to the following page when i click a button

```
http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2
```

I want to edit the existing url inside the controller without hard coding the whole url as IP and Port can be changed. How can I achieve this?

Although I used `$location.path("http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2");`
What is does is it appends to the current url as follows

```
http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2#http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2
```

How can I redirect to the required page ?

Comment: You might want to refer to the [documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-a-navigation-link-routerlink) of Angular. I think you should define [routes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-routes).

Comment: Can I see the routes?

Comment: I haven't created any routes. Can't I do this without using routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using $window.location and it was successful. Non of the other methods worked.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

$scope.redirect = function()
{
$window.location = "http://IP:Port/......";

};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a not so similar issue where I had to convert the variable to a string and then modify the string.  Then convert back to the proper data type.

Comment: I have the created url but I am unable to redirect to the page when the button is clicked

Comment: Are you unable to get the onclick to redirect or is it that the url is incorrect.  http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2#http://IP:Port/?myId=this-is-my-test-page2 instead of just "http://IP:Port/?myid=this-is-my-test-page2"?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has its own routing. **Everything right of # is the Angular routing (client side routing). Everything to the left of the # sign is your MVC/WebApi routing (server side routing).** This is the essence of a single page application.

If you want to change the server side routing you need to do the redirect on the server side, so do a request to the server to change the url. If you want to change the client side (Angular) routing you need to use the "$location.path('')" in your angular code. Be aware that you cannot change anything to the left of the # sign on the client side.

You are trying to change the server side piece of the url, so you need to do a request to the server to change the url.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23975199/when-to-use-client-side-routing-or-server-side-routing) for more information about the two: